# Why will it show null pointer exception in the jsf file?

Tags: java, jsf

This is my jsf file

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">
    <h:head>

    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        <f:view>
            <h:form>
                <h1><h:outputText value="List"/></h1>
                <h:dataTable value="#{manageBean.tours}" var="item">
                    <h:column>
                        <f:facet name="header">
                            <h:outputText value="Tourid"/>
                        </f:facet>
                        <h:outputText value="#{item.tourid}"/>
                    </h:column>
                 </h:dataTable>
            </h:form>
        </f:view>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

This is my manage bean

```
public class manageBean {
    private Tourpackage tour;
    private List<Tourpackage> tours;
    private sessionBean session;

    public manageBean() {
    }

    public List<Tourpackage> getTours() {
        return session.retrieveTour();
    }

    public void setTours(List<Tourpackage> tours) {
        this.tours = tours;
    }  
}
```

This is my session bean

```
public class sessionBean {
    private EntityManager em;

    public List<Tourpackage> retrieveTour(){
        Query query = em.createNamedQuery("Tourpackage.findAll");
        return query.getResultList();
    }
}
```

This is my entity class (exclude the variables and methods)

```
@NamedQueries({
@NamedQuery(name = "Reservation.findAll", query = "SELECT r FROM Reservation r"),
@NamedQuery(name = "Reservation.findByReservationid", query = "SELECT r FROM Reservation r WHERE r.reservationid = :reservationid"),
@NamedQuery(name = "Reservation.findByReservationdate", query = "SELECT r FROM Reservation r WHERE r.reservationdate = :reservationdate")})
```

public class Reservation implements Serializable {

Any1 here expert in JSF???
i got null pointer exception everytime i run the jsf file through netbeans, the database i used is in the netbeans. forgive me for the terrible format.

Stack Trace

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at manageBean.getTours(manageBean.java:23)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
at javax.el.BeanELResolver.getValue(BeanELResolver.java:363)
at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver._getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:176)
at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver.getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:203)
at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:138)
at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:183)
at com.sun.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:224)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:109)
at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:194)
at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:182)
at javax.faces.component.UIData.getValue(UIData.java:731)
at javax.faces.component.UIData.getDataModel(UIData.java:1798)
at javax.faces.component.UIData.setRowIndexWithoutRowStatePreserved(UIData.java:484)
at javax.faces.component.UIData.setRowIndex(UIData.java:473)
at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.TableRenderer.encodeBegin(TableRenderer.java:81)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeBegin(UIComponentBase.java:820)
at javax.faces.component.UIData.encodeBegin(UIData.java:1118)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1755)
at javax.faces.render.Renderer.encodeChildren(Renderer.java:168)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:845)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1757)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1760)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1760)
at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:402)
at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:131)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:121)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139)
at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:594)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1550)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:281)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:655)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:595)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:161)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:331)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:231)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$AdapterCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:317)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:195)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:860)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:757)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1056)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:229)
at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

---

After applying a proposed solution, I have new problems:

```
com.sun.faces.mgbean.ManagedBeanCreationException: An error occurred performing resource injection on managed bean manage
at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanBuilder.injectResources(BeanBuilder.java:211)
at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanBuilder.build(BeanBuilder.java:103)
at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanManager.createAndPush(BeanManager.java:409)
at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanManager.create(BeanManager.java:269)
at com.sun.faces.el.ManagedBeanELResolver.resolveBean(ManagedBeanELResolver.java:244)
at com.sun.faces.el.ManagedBeanELResolver.getValue(ManagedBeanELResolver.java:116)
at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver._getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:176)
at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver.getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:203)
at com.sun.el.parser.AstIdentifier.getValue(AstIdentifier.java:103)
at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:179)
at com.sun.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:224)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:109)
at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:194)
at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:182)
at javax.faces.component.UIData.getValue(UIData.java:731)
at javax.faces.component.UIData.getDataModel(UIData.java:1798)
at javax.faces.component.UIData.setRowIndexWithoutRowStatePreserved(UIData.java:484)
at javax.faces.component.UIData.setRowIndex(UIData.java:473)
at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.TableRenderer.encodeBegin(TableRenderer.java:81)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeBegin(UIComponentBase.java:820)
at javax.faces.component.UIData.encodeBegin(UIData.java:1118)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1755)
at javax.faces.render.Renderer.encodeChildren(Renderer.java:168)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:845)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1757)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1760)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1760)
at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:402)
at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:131)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:121)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139)
at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:594)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1550)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:281)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:655)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:595)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:161)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:331)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:231)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$AdapterCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:317)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:195)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:860)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:757)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1056)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:229)
at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)




Caused by: com.sun.faces.spi.InjectionProviderException: com.sun.enterprise.container.common.spi.util.InjectionException: Exception attempting to inject Remote ejb-ref name=manage/tour,Remote 3.x interface =entities.Tourpackage,ejb-link=null,lookup=,mappedName=,jndi-name=entities.Tourpackage,refType=Session into class manage: Lookup failed for 'java:comp/env/manage/tour' in SerialContext[myEnv={java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialInitContextFactory, java.naming.factory.state=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl, java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.sun.enterprise.naming}
at org.glassfish.faces.integration.GlassFishInjectionProvider.inject(GlassFishInjectionProvider.java:194)
at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanBuilder.injectResources(BeanBuilder.java:205)
... 56 more




Caused by: com.sun.enterprise.container.common.spi.util.InjectionException: Exception attempting to inject Remote ejb-ref name=manage/tour,Remote 3.x interface =entities.Tourpackage,ejb-link=null,lookup=,mappedName=,jndi-name=entities.Tourpackage,refType=Session into class manage: Lookup failed for 'java:comp/env/manage/tour' in SerialContext[myEnv={java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialInitContextFactory, java.naming.factory.state=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl, java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.sun.enterprise.naming}
at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.util.InjectionManagerImpl._inject(InjectionManagerImpl.java:703)
at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.util.InjectionManagerImpl.inject(InjectionManagerImpl.java:470)
at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.util.InjectionManagerImpl.injectInstance(InjectionManagerImpl.java:171)
at org.glassfish.faces.integration.GlassFishInjectionProvider.inject(GlassFishInjectionProvider.java:184)
... 57 more




Caused by: javax.naming.NamingException: Lookup failed for 'java:comp/env/manage/tour' in SerialContext[myEnv={java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialInitContextFactory, java.naming.factory.state=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl, java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.sun.enterprise.naming} [Root exception is javax.naming.NamingException: Exception resolving Ejb for 'Remote ejb-ref name=manage/tour,Remote 3.x interface =entities.Tourpackage,ejb-link=null,lookup=,mappedName=,jndi-name=entities.Tourpackage,refType=Session' .  Actual (possibly internal) Remote JNDI name used for lookup is 'entities.Tourpackage#entities.Tourpackage' [Root exception is javax.naming.NamingException: Lookup failed for 'entities.Tourpackage#entities.Tourpackage' in SerialContext[myEnv={java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialInitContextFactory, java.naming.factory.state=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl, java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.sun.enterprise.naming} [Root exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: entities.Tourpackage#entities.Tourpackage not found]]]
at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:518)
at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:455)
at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:411)
at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:411)
at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.util.InjectionManagerImpl._inject(InjectionManagerImpl.java:599)
... 60 more




Caused by: javax.naming.NamingException: Exception resolving Ejb for 'Remote ejb-ref name=manage/tour,Remote 3.x interface =entities.Tourpackage,ejb-link=null,lookup=,mappedName=,jndi-name=entities.Tourpackage,refType=Session' .  Actual (possibly internal) Remote JNDI name used for lookup is 'entities.Tourpackage#entities.Tourpackage' [Root exception is javax.naming.NamingException: Lookup failed for 'entities.Tourpackage#entities.Tourpackage' in SerialContext[myEnv={java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialInitContextFactory, java.naming.factory.state=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl, java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.sun.enterprise.naming} [Root exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: entities.Tourpackage#entities.Tourpackage not found]]
at com.sun.ejb.EjbNamingReferenceManagerImpl.resolveEjbReference(EjbNamingReferenceManagerImpl.java:191)
at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.ComponentEnvManagerImpl$EjbReferenceProxy.create(ComponentEnvManagerImpl.java:1109)
at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.GlassfishNamingManagerImpl.lookup(GlassfishNamingManagerImpl.java:776)
at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.GlassfishNamingManagerImpl.lookup(GlassfishNamingManagerImpl.java:744)
at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.JavaURLContext.lookup(JavaURLContext.java:169)
at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:498)
... 64 more




Caused by: javax.naming.NamingException: Lookup failed for 'entities.Tourpackage#entities.Tourpackage' in SerialContext[myEnv={java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialInitContextFactory, java.naming.factory.state=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl, java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.sun.enterprise.naming} [Root exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: entities.Tourpackage#entities.Tourpackage not found]
at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:518)
at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:455)
at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:411)
at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:411)
at com.sun.ejb.EjbNamingReferenceManagerImpl.resolveEjbReference(EjbNamingReferenceManagerImpl.java:186)
... 69 more




Caused by: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: entities.Tourpackage#entities.Tourpackage not found
at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.TransientContext.doLookup(TransientContext.java:248)
at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.TransientContext.lookup(TransientContext.java:215)
at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContextProviderImpl.lookup(SerialContextProviderImpl.java:77)
at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.LocalSerialContextProviderImpl.lookup(LocalSerialContextProviderImpl.java:119)
at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:505)
... 73 more
```

Comment: What is the error message/stack trace?

Comment: `session` is null so in `getTours()` method you have NPE.

Comment: Now that you've posted the stack trace, it's pretty clear what the error is (though in future posts, in addition to posting the trace right away, you should also point out which line it refers to). You should pay more attention to what the error message is telling you. It can really save time.

Comment: @iamnotmaynard if you have worked with JSF before, you won't need the stacktrace at all to understand the problem.

Comment: You didn't initialize `session`, did you?

Comment: Looks like you haven't read my answer update. Also, please don't update the code with problems otherwise provided answer will be useless.

Comment: thx for all the answers it worked out, somehow...

Comment: @Lantz if some answer helped you the most, please mark it as the answer by click the check below the rep and the up/down arrows

Comment: It would certainly be nicer if JSF said which EL expression caused the `NullPointerException`, but, the way JSF presents it, you have to create an exception breakpoint in order to find out what went wrong...

Answer (score 4):

`sessionBean session` in your managed bean is never initialized. Turn it into an EJB if you're in a Java EE 6 environment:

```
@Stateless
public class sessionBean {

    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "yourPersistenceContextFileName")
private EntityManager em;
    //...
}
```

Then just call it as an EJB in your managed bean. Also, you should retrieve the data in the `@PostConstruct` method, not in the getter since he getter methods can be called several times]([Why JSF calls getters multiple times](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2090033/1065197)):

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class manageBean {

    @EJB
    private sessionBean session;
    private List<Tourpackage> tours;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        tours = session.retrieveTour();
    }

    //plain getters/setters
}
```

Comment: thx man, but not theres a new error, i will edit the question to show it

Comment: @Lantz I've updated my answer in order to show a basic Java EE 6 solution.

Answer (score 0):

annoate your classes with `@ManagedBean` or add them in the `faces-config.xml`.
if you are using cdi annotate them with `@Named`.
otherwise you can not acces your via el expression.

**offtopic**

By convention, Java type names usually start with an uppercase letter:

manageBean -> ManageBean

sessionBean -> SessionBean

Answer (score 0):

There are no annotations in your code! Did you just forget to include them in your post or they are missing from the code?
At least you have to annotate manageBean as @ManagedBean (or @Named @Statefull) and add @Inject annotation to your injected objects (EntityManager and sessionBean), otherwise the container will never handle their lifetime (i.e. instantiate them for you so you don't get NPEs)

Comment: I suggest you include the annotations so we can be more precise to our answers. It's vital information and lack of them leads to assumptions. IMHO one should also include imports in order to verify which package is used...